# Best ways of passing strings from C to Ada

Tags: c, string, ada

I have a requirement where I need to pass a string from a C function to an Ada function (a C-Ada binding application).

C function:

```
extern void ada_func_print_string(char*);
void Pass_String()
{
  char str[] = "Hello_Ada";
  ada_func_print_string(str);
}
```

Ada function:

Spec:

```
pragma Export (Convention    => C,
               Entity        => Ada_Print_String,
               External_Name => "ada_func_print_string");
```

Body:

```
procedure Ada_Print_String (C_Source : Interfaces.C.char_array)
   Ada_Str : String := Interfaces.C.To_Ada(Item     => C_Source,
                                           Trim_Nul => True);
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(Ada_Str);       
end Ada_Print_String;
```

The above code pretty much works fine without any hassle. The question I have is whether the declaration of formal parameter **C_Source** is good to be a **Interfaces.C.char_array** or it should better be **Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr**? What is the difference between the two in regard to this application? Is there any fatality using among these two types in here?

Comment: Great, it really helped!!

Answer (score 3):

[*Ada 95 Rationale, §B.2 C Interface Package, §B.2.2 Strings*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p3-b.html#2) may offer some perspective on this. Note that [`Interfaces.C`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-3.html) is a [pure](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-10-2-1.html) package that provides the *basic* types and subprograms that allow an Ada subprogram to accept a C string. In contrast, [`Interfaces.C.Strings`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-3-1.html) allows "an Ada program to allocate, reference, update, and free C-style strings" via the private type `chars_ptr`. In your example, the C compiler [must](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.4.5.html) append a null terminator to your string literal, but it's possible for an errant C program to create mischief.

```
char str[] = {'H','e','l','l'};
```

Verify that your code handles the resulting `Terminator_Error`.